# Specifics of Setting up a VPN

Tags: networking, router, vpn

I have two small offices, and one office has a NAS storage, say office 1. I want office 2 to also have access to the NAS via a intuitive interface - shared drives, as seen by office 1 employees.

If i decide to go for setting up a VPN connection, should i create a lan to lan VPN, such that office 2 router is directed to office 1 router, or should i create a single client machine to office 1 connection, where a person connects to office 1 by opening a vPN client on his machine, and dialing the ip-address of office 1 VPN server.

If i use option 1, wouldn't it sacrifice speed of internet, since even for normal web browsing, traffic is being routed to office 1 router?

Also, is such a setup easy to do, or do i need to call in an IT company.

Comment: This question is too generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I downvoted your question for being too generic. Consider investing more own research and coming back with specific questions.

To get you started: You are better off creating a site-to-site VPN. All your clients at site 2 then can access your resources at site 1. Implementation largely depends on your VPN solution. If you worry about bandwidth, research split VPN: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling